# About async/await in koa2

Tags: node.js, async-await, koa, ecmascript-2017

I use `async/await` in koa2 like following

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const app = new Koa();

app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
  await next()
  console.log("1------>"+Date.now())
});

app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
  await next()
  console.log("2------>"+Date.now())
});

app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
  await next()
  console.log("3------>"+Date.now())
});

app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
  await next()
  console.log("4------>"+Date.now())
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Run this code, I will get the log like this

```
4------>1526575713792
3------>1526575713794
2------>1526575713795
1------>1526575713795
```

And here are my questions

1. What's the `next` in `app.use(async (ctx, next)`, is it a function?
2. `await next()` in each `app.use` function means `wait, please run the next app.use first`, if has no next `app.use`, ignore it, and run the code in last `app.use` fuction, am I right?
3. If I change the first one `app.use` to `app.use(async (ctx) => { console.log("1------>"+Date.now())});`, and run it, the result has only one records `1------>1526576945380`. I thought the second `app.use` function will continue running, and I will get the result like this

   1------>1526576945360

   4------>1526575761869

   3------>1526575761869

   2------>1526575761869

So, can anyone help me? and explain for me? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. yes `next`  is a function, `console.log(typeof next)` would have shown you that.
2. Yes, calling `next` will instruct koa to execute the next middleware that was registered using e.g. `use`, and returns a Promise that is resolve as soon as the next middlewae is resolve, with `await` in front of that `next` your code will wait there until that Promise is resolved.
3. why do you expect that the next middlewares that was registered with `use` are called? You don't call `next` so you *terminate* at in this middleware. `await` is a js functionality to wait for a Promise to be resolved. `next`  is the koa functionality to execute the next middleware.

Comment: I see, thank you so much, and for your third answer, I don't have the expectation, and I thought all of `app.use` will be called in an orderly way if there's no `await next`.